# Выравнить два блока по нижнему краю

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Всем привет! Я backend-щик, а поставили задачу по верстке. Имеется два блока A и Б, у которых может быть разная высота. Вопрос, как их выровнять по нижнему краю как указано на рисунке.

[image: Рисунок]

Answer (score 2):

Используя **Flexbox**:

```css
.db {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="db">
    <div class="d1">
        текст текст
    </div>
    <div class="d2">
        текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте этим блокам `vertical-align: bottom;`

```css
.a,.b{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: silver;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.a{
  height: 200px;
}

.b{
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```